# newbie to ASP.NET need help configuring wsaspnet websockets server

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, websocket

I'm new to ASP.NET (did some classic ASPs back in the day, but my how things have changed!) and need to get a proof-of-concept of a browser talking to a server using websockets up-and-running.

I downloaded http://wsaspnet.codeplex.com/

I installed it in a directory called "counter" in my local IIS webroot (counter contains the folders Web, WsTestClient and the file wsaspnet.sln).

I figured out that I needed to copy Global.asax from /counter/Web to / :p

When I access http://localhost/counter/Web/Default.aspx I get the following error:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'WebSocks' does not exist in the current context
Source Error:
Line 4: void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 5: {
Line 6:     WebSocks.WebSockServer.Start();
Line 7: }
```

I realize that this is because the server can't find the code from the file /counter/Web/App_Code/WebSockServer.cs, where the namespace and object are defined.

How do I tell the server where to find this code? I'm guessing that it's a simple matter but I don't know ASP.NET well enough (read: AT ALL) to figure it out :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May be you didn't include the correct 'using' in the begining of the code? It seams a problem of namespaces. Where is your global.asax file? It must be in the same website as WebSockServer.cs, so that it is abled to see it.

Comment: They're on the same website.  I didn't make any changes to the code, I'm just trying to run it out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that everything in the Web folder had to go in the webroot.